# Firebase rules condition on a specific child value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I wrote this rules:

```
"users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "username":{
          ".write": "data.val() == 'null'"
        }
     }
},
```

Goal: User can change his username only if its value is "null". 
Unfortunately it's not working (I tried with validate too). Am I writing this wrongly or is this just impossible ?

Edit: My structure is like rules:

```
/rules
   /id
     /username
     /email
     /state
     /...
```

`firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({ username: "test"})` → FIREBASE WARNING: update at /users/myid failed: permission_denied

`firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+"/username").set("test")` → FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/myid/username failed: permission_denied

Comment: I would expect that to work.  Could you show your code and database structure?

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. It's not about rule, It's about query: firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({ username: username }) and I just found error was: FIREBASE WARNING: update at /users/myid failed: permission_denied. I think it's looking only at /users/id where write is indeed false, and not at /users/id/username. I tried to change with firebase.database().ref("users/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+"/username").set(username) and got FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/myid/username failed: permission_denied i don't get it. Structure added

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Your rules require that the `username` is equal to `"null"`. Your write operations set `username` to `"test"`. Since `"test" <> "null"` the write is rejected.

Comment: User can choose his username only once time at registration (if his username is equals to "null" then he can changes it). That's why the rule isn't about newData, it's about existing data (data.val() is that correct ?)

Comment: I didn't solve the problem I'm using a cloud function in the meantime.